# CSS hover анимация

Tags: html, css, hover, transition

При наведении на картинку у меня срабатывает анимация, но я не могу сделать так, чтобы такой же анимацией она возвращалась обратно. Так же она просто РЕЗКО возвращается в исходное положение.
Пробовал через ::after ::before, что-то такое, видимо не понимаю...

```css
.playblock_text img:hover{
  transform: rotateX(4.32deg) rotateY(-7.98deg) rotate(7deg);
  transition-duration: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="playblock_text">
  <img src="https://store-images.s-microsoft.com/image/apps.47867.13879366447690213.ff0dcdf1-af01-4af7-b105-db57cef9cb67.771cf851-92c5-4d8a-9314-5cfc91541202?mode=scale&q=90&h=200&w=200&background=%230078D7" alt="" style="height: 300px;">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.playblock_text img {
   transition: transform ease 2s;
}
.playblock_text img:hover{
   transform: rotateX(4.32deg) rotateY(-7.98deg) rotate(7deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="playblock_text">
  <img src="https://store-images.s-microsoft.com/image/apps.47867.13879366447690213.ff0dcdf1-af01-4af7-b105-db57cef9cb67.771cf851-92c5-4d8a-9314-5cfc91541202?mode=scale&q=90&h=200&w=200&background=%230078D7" alt="" style="height: 300px;">
</div>
```